# Pure JavaScript alternative to jQuery's .not()

Tags: javascript, jquery

What would be the JS alternative to `.not()` from jQuery? I have `$(".form :input").not`, but need to transfer that to pure JS. Is there a guide that could help me?

```
 var input = $(".form :input").not('button, [type="button"], [type="submit"]').on({
input: return
});
```

I'm looking to do that in JS

Comment: What? I'm looking for an alternative.... @Mike

Comment: you should tell us that what .not() function is for in JQuery. May be someone don't know JQuery, however he knows JavaScript so with your explain he can understand and answer to your question in JS.

Comment: Or just give the things you want a common class and not worry about the not.

Comment: @Ali **[.not(selector)](http://api.jquery.com/:not/)** is to remove selected elements, not a negation operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equivalent in plain JS would be something like this

```
var forms = document.querySelectorAll('.form'),
    inputs = [];

for (var i = forms.length; i--;) {
    var els = forms[i].querySelectorAll('input, textarea, select');

    for (var j = els.length; j--;) {
        if (els[j].type != 'button' && els[j].type != 'submit') {
            inputs.push(els[j]);
            els[j].addEventListener('input', cback, false);
        }
    }
}

function cback(event) {
    var b = [];

    for (var i = inputs.length; i--;) {
        if (!inputs[i].value.length) b.push(inputs[i]);
    }

    var l1 = b.length;
    var l2 = inputs.length;
    var top = document.querySelectorAll('.top');

    for (var j = top.length; j--;) {
        top[j].style.width = 100 - (l1 / l2) * 100 + "%";
    }
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/g7HAC/1/)

Answer (score 5):

Modern browser do support a *NOT* clause in `querySelectorAll()`:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".form :input:not(...)");
```

Example ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HM7xd/2/)):

```html
<div>This should be colored!</div>
<div>This should be colored!</div>
<div id="this-not">This must not colored!</div>
<div>This should be colored!</div>
<div>This should be colored!</div>
```

```js
var matchedElements = document.querySelectorAll("div:not(#this-not)");
for (var i=0; i<matchedElements.length; i++) {
    matchedElements.item(i).style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

Comment: I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: querySelectorAll is not defined fort.min.js:1
(anonymous function)` when trying to use it....

Comment: then use `document.querySelectorAll("");`

Comment: Then I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': '.form :input' is not a valid selector. ` @derek_duncan

Comment: it's just "input", not ":input". of course, the QSA version won't map that selector to textareas and select and buttons, but that's the breaks. i like "[name]" to hit form elements...

Comment: And I once again get `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function ` @dandavis

Comment: something like document.querySelectorAll(".form [name]:not(:invalid)") should work, depending on your NOT clause.

Comment: @user302975 Please show us the "converted" code. I also added a simple example in my answer.

Comment: Also I'm not trying to use `id` at the moment, rather just plain `input`

Comment: based on your updated question, you can do it with a few comma-joined input:not() specifiers...

Comment: Posting an answer on how to would be more then appreciated @dandavis

Comment: @user302975 See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HM7xd/4/). Note that `:input` from jQuery also covers textareas and probably some more elements ([jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/)).

Comment: Here's what I'm trying to use `var input = document.querySelectorAll(".form input:not([type=button]):not([type=submit])").on({
    input: return
});` But I get `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function `

Comment: @user302975 `on` is a jQuery function which is not available on "native" (=non-jQuery) objects. [Updated example.](http://jsfiddle.net/HM7xd/5/)

Comment: So what would be the alternative to all of my code? Since `on` is jQuery?

Comment: Or the alternative to simply `on`?

Comment: @user302975 I've already posted a link. Here is a more refined version: http://jsfiddle.net/HM7xd/6/

Comment: But this part specially `on({
    input: return
});` It doesn't seem to work

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52622/discussion-between-comfreek-and-user302975)

Answer (score 3):

You could also use `.filter()` to exclude items in your array. You would use it like so (example from MDN):

```
function isBigEnough(element) {
  return element >= 10;
}
var filtered = [12, 5, 8, 130, 44].filter(isBigEnough);
// filtered is [12, 130, 44]
```

It's supported in all modern browsers and IE9+. See [Array.prototype.filter() on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for more information.

Unfortunately `.filter()` only works on Arrays so we have to do some extra manipulating to filter a `NodeList`.

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li class="not-me">3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
var filter = Array.prototype.filter;

var excludeByClassName = function(className) {
    return function (element) {
        return element.className != className;
    };
};

var LIs = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
// [li, li, li.not-me, li, li]

var filteredLIs = filter.call(LIs, excludeByClassName('not-me'));
// [li, li, li, li]
```

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/82zjY/) for a working example.

Comment: Might also include how to get an `Array`. Neither `jQuery` collections nor `NodeList`s are `Array`s and won't inherit their methods.

Comment: MDN provides some workarounds: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList