# Pure Javascript how to select all selectors but NOT this

Tags: javascript

How to use pure javascript to select all `.dummy` classes but NOT `THIS`? 
I searched a while but can't find the answer I want.

e.g. if I click the first `.dummy` div, I want to select all `.dummy` divs but not the one I clicked.

jQuery way to achieve is like below,

```
var $dummy = $('.dummy');
$dummy.on('click', function(){
    $dummy.not(this).......
});
```

But I'd like to know how to achieve it by using pure javascript

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.dummy').forEach(function(e, i){
  e.addEventListener('click', function(){
    console.log(document.querySelectorAll('.dummy').not(this)); 
    // WRONG not working, also querySelectorAll('.dummy:not(this)'));
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="dummy">One</div>
<div class="dummy">Two</div>
<div class="dummy">Three</div>
<div class="dummy">Four</div>
```

Comment: What is `this` meant to be in the context of your question? At the moment, it's the event listener function, which wouldn't be a DOM element.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve within the click handler?  querySelectorAll returns a NodeList which does not have a method "not". https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList

Comment: `[...document.querySelectorAll('.dummy')].filter(n => n !== this)` --- it would be an array after all, but perhaps it works for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pure JavaScript alternative to jQuery's .not()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23640528/pure-javascript-alternative-to-jquerys-not)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply filter an array of elements using the built-in `Array.prototype.filter()` function to find what you're looking for; however, `document.querySelectorAll` returns a Node List object, not an array.

#### Converting a Node List to an array

The tricky part is that you'll first need to convert your Node List object into an array before you can filter it.

This can be done two ways:

1. The ES6 way (Spread Operator).

   `[...document.querySelectorAll('.dummy')];` .
2. The pre-ES6 way (Array.prototype.slice)

   `Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.dummy'));` .

#### Filtering your results

You already have `e` storing a reference to each of the dummy elements, which can be used in your event listener to filter out the matching element.

```
elements.filter(function(element) {
  return element !== e;
});
```

---

## Complete Solution

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.dummy').forEach(function(e, i){
  e.addEventListener('click', function(){
    var elements = [...document.querySelectorAll('.dummy')];

    var otherElements = elements.filter(function(element) {
      return element !== e;
    });
    
    console.log(otherElements);
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="dummy">One</div>
<div class="dummy">Two</div>
<div class="dummy">Three</div>
<div class="dummy">Four</div>
```

Comment: Nice!  Trick here is to convert the NodeList to an Array in order to use filter.  Here is an article with more on this: https://hackernoon.com/htmlcollection-nodelist-and-array-of-objects-da42737181f9

Comment: Yeah this is what I was going to suggest first until I realized NodeList didn't have a `.filter`. Nice trick to get it into a normal array.

Comment: Thanks for the link @WilliamFleming, I've explained that a little better in my answer.

Comment: You forgot the "other" ES6 way: `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.dummy'))`

Comment: Keep in mind that `.dummy` won't necessarily be siblings here. To do that you'd want to find the parent first and then use that parent element to call `querySelectorAll` (e.g. `document.getElementById("some-parent").querySelectorAll(".dummy")`)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to the already given answers (which are quite usable but not necessarily equivalent), if the elements have some other identifying attribute, you could use that like so:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.dummy').forEach(function(e, i){
  e.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    console.log(document.querySelectorAll('.dummy:not([myattr="' + event.target.getAttribute("myattr") + '"])'));
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="dummy" myattr="1">One</div>
<div class="dummy" myattr="2">Two</div>
<div class="dummy" myattr="3">Three</div>
<div class="dummy" myattr="4">Four</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Every element has it's siblings in a LinkedList attached to it on `this.previousSibling` and `this.nextSibling`. While you can filter after calling querySelectorAll again, I wanted to show an option where you don't need to call up the lookups again. Also, you can be sure that these are actually siblings and not other `.dummy` on the page (you can also do this by setting the proper context for `querySelectorAll`)

```js
/**
 * @param acc  {Array}  An array to push onto
 * @param el   {Node}   The element to cycle over
 */
function getPrevSiblings(acc, el) {
  if(el.previousSibling) {
   // Ignores #text elements
   if(el.previousSibling.nodeName !== "#text" ) {
     acc.push(el.previousSibling);
    }

    return getPrevSiblings(acc, el.previousSibling)
  }
  return acc;
}

/**
 * @param acc  {Array}  An array to push onto
 * @param el   {Node}   The element to cycle over
 */
function getNextSiblings(acc, el) {
  if(el.nextSibling) {
   // Ignores #text elements
   if(el.previousSibling.nodeName !== "#text" ) {
     acc.push(el.nextSibling);
    }
    return getNextSiblings(acc, el.nextSibling)
  }
  return acc;
}

document.querySelectorAll('.dummy').forEach(function(e, i){
  e.addEventListener('click', function(){
    var prev = getPrevSiblings([], this)
    var next = getNextSiblings([], this)
    var allElsForLogging = [].concat(prev, next);
    console.log(allElsForLogging); 
  });
});
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="dummy">One</div>
  <div class="dummy">Two</div>
  <div class="dummy">Three</div>
  <div class="dummy">Four</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Code could be cleaned up a little, but I didn't want to distract with factories and currying.

Answer (score 1):

Extends built-in object "NodeList" as following:

```js
//Extends NodeList
NodeList.prototype.not = function ( cssSelectorOrNodeOrNodeList ) {
    //Change object name(constructor.name) to "NodeList" from "Array" in console window
    let list = ( () => { class NodeList extends Array {} return new NodeList(); } )(), excludes;

    if ( typeof cssSelectorOrNodeOrNodeList === "string" ) excludes = document.querySelectorAll( cssSelectorOrNodeOrNodeList );
    else if ( cssSelectorOrNodeOrNodeList instanceof NodeList ) excludes = cssSelectorOrNodeOrNodeList;
    else if ( cssSelectorOrNodeOrNodeList instanceof Node ) excludes = [ cssSelectorOrNodeOrNodeList ];
    
    if ( excludes === undefined || !excludes.length ) return this;

    for ( const node of this ) {
        let flag = true;
        for ( const compare of excludes ) {
            if ( node === compare ) {
                flag = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if ( flag ) list.push( node );
    }
    Object.setPrototypeOf( list, NodeList.prototype );

    return list;
};

//Object information
{
    let test = document.childNodes.not( document.body );
    console.log( test.constructor.name ); //NodeList
    console.log( test.constructor === NodeList ); //true
    console.log( test instanceof NodeList ); //true
    console.log( test instanceof Array ); //false
    console.dir( test ); //NodeList .... not Array ....;
}

//Your test code

document.querySelectorAll('.dummy').forEach(function(e, i){
  e.addEventListener('click', function(){
    console.log(document.querySelectorAll('.dummy').not(this)); 
    // WRONG not working, also querySelectorAll('.dummy:not(this)'));
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="dummy">One</div>
<div class="dummy">Two</div>
<div class="dummy">Three</div>
<div class="dummy">Four</div>
```

You can use this as just you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

You could just loop back over the elements and use an `if`

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.dummy').forEach(function(e, i){
  e.addEventListener('click', function(){
    console.log(document.querySelectorAll('.dummy').forEach((e) => {
      if (e !== this) {
        e.style.color = 'red';
      }
    }));
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="dummy">One</div>
<div class="dummy">Two</div>
<div class="dummy">Three</div>
<div class="dummy">Four</div>
```